# Web API in an MVC project not working after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an mvc project which has a web api controller. The web api has a Get method which returns a list of objects. This call is made from the client using JQuery ajax method and the data is exchanged as JSON object. Everything works fine when I run the application from within Visual Studio. The pages load correctly and on clicking the 'Search' button, the ajax call is made and the records are loaded successfully on the page. The routes are properly mapped to the areas and there is absolutely no problem.
The problem arises when I publish the application in IIS and then try to 'Search' the records. On clicking the 'Search' button, I get 500 Internal Server Error which I believe suggests that the web api service is not available to the application and is not running.
Do I need to deploy/publish the web api separately? If thats the case then how can I do that deploy it separately given that it is part of the same MVC project (there is no separate Web API project).

Comment: You need to find the exact error that is happening. You can do it with logging or setting `customerErrors mode="Off"` in web.config

Comment: Try this. Right click the project, select 'unload project'. Then edit the csproj. If your web api section has 'none include' as a tag, change this to 'content include' like the other xml tags. Then, publish again.

Comment: There is no customeerrors tag in the web config file. There is no web api section in the csproj file.

Comment: @user2611292 you should add it yourself if it's not there, you can google how to do that. After that in your response you will get the actual error and the stacktrace

Comment: Thanks @VG there seems to be no difference in the response. the error extract using fiddler is below: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request.   Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. Could not load type 'IncomApps.VBL.MvcApplication'.

Comment: The namespace IncomApps.VBL is the namespace used in global.asax.cs and the class is MvcApplication